# Redering bold header in markdown after kable

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

If I  knit a document to `md` using `kable("html")` for a table and load it up to GitHub the bold header will not be rendered after the chunk.

````
```{r}
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  kable("html") 
```
````

**Some Header** (This is not bold in the final document: used ** **)

... next chunk.

`````
```[r}

iris %>%
  distinct(Species)
````
`````

**Some Header 2** (This is bold in the final document: used ** **)

Answer (score 0):

You mean a code chunk like this:

```
knitr::kable(head(iris),caption = "iris dataset",format = "html")
```

**bold**

Also:
-kable is part of knitr (or perhaps kableExtra), not a package in itself. Please check.
-Check extra ")" in summarise(n = n))